# Confusing definitions of standing waves

Tags: waves, definition, resonance

I have come across two different definitions of standing waves, which confuses me since I cannot relate these two definitions.

**Question**

For standing waves, how is resonance related to  superposition in definition 2?

*Definition 1*

[image: Definition of Standing waves in one of the textbooks]

*Definition 2*

Standing waves are formed when two waves of the same nature and same amplitude travel in opposite directions through the same medium.

Comment: The two definitions are the same. In your "Definition 1" the wave created by the vibrator reflects off the wall and travels left back towards the vibrator. So just like "Definition 2" we have two waves travelling in opposite directions.

Comment: Ok. But how is resonance coming into the picture in definition 1?

Comment: The frequency and length of the wire determines the phase of the reflected wave, and we get a resonance only when the phase of the reflected wave differs from the phase of the original wave by a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Ok. Does resonance mean resulting in a maximum amplitude?

Comment: Yes, the resonance is when the amplitude of the wave formed by the original and the reflected waves is a maximum.

Comment: That explains how the two definitions are related since in standing waves constructive interference is occurring all the time. I'll mark this as the answer if you could post it.